# Translating a for loop from c# to python (ironpython)

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I'm translating a chunk of code I have to use, from C# to Python.
I'm not fluent in C#.
How would you translate the code?:

```
Line foundLine = null;
for (int j = 0; null == foundLine && j < 2; j++)
{
do some stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the `python` translation for the above `C#` code:

```
foundLine = None;
j = 0
while j < 2 and foundLine is None:
    #do some stuff;
    j += 1
```